# How to avoid invoking init() in sheet when parent View updated in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

TestView3 can show 2 sheets: TestView4 and TestView5. TestView4 has @State value which initialize from TestView3. TestView5 has @ObservedObject value which initialize from TestView3 too.

When I toggle the global value (global.on), it will update TestView3, then cause to TestView4 or TestView5 init().

Q1. How to avoid invoking init() in TestView4 or TestView5 when TestView3 updated? How to totally isolate a view with a sheet from the view? Or any update in a view will affect the sheet, it's awful.

Q2. The behaviors of init() in TestView4 or TestView5 are not the same. The local @State in TestView4 will NOT changed in init(). But the local @ObservedObject will changed in init(). Why? It's so weird. How to make @ObservedObject NOT changed in init() because of TestView3 update?

You can test following code, the trace log is so weird.

```
class Global: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = Global()
    @Published var on: Bool = false
}

class Local: ObservableObject {
    @Published var on: Bool = false
    init(_ on: Bool) {
        self.on = on
    }
}

struct TestView3: View {
    @ObservedObject var global = Global.shared
    @State private var sheetShowing = false
    @State private var sheetShowingId = 4
    var body: some View {
        print("test view3 body, glabel on = \(global.on)"); return
        VStack {
            Text("Global").foregroundColor(global.on ? .red : .gray).onTapGesture {
                self.global.on.toggle()
            }.padding()
            Button(action: {
                self.sheetShowing = true
                self.sheetShowingId = 4
                print("test view3, will show test view4")
            }) { Text("Show TestView4") }.padding()
            Button(action: {
                self.sheetShowing = true
                self.sheetShowingId = 5
                print("test view3, will show test view5")
            }) { Text("Show TestView5") }.padding()
        }.sheet(isPresented: $sheetShowing) {
            if self.sheetShowingId == 4 {
                TestView4(on: self.global.on)
            } else {
                TestView5(on: self.global.on)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestView4: View {
    @State private var on: Bool
    init(on: Bool) {
        self._on = State(initialValue: on)
        print("test view4 init, glabel on = \(Global.shared.on), local on = \(self.on)")
    }
    var body: some View {
        print("test view4 body, glabel on = \(Global.shared.on), local on = \(on)"); return
        VStack {
            Text("TestView4").padding()
            Text("Local").foregroundColor(on ? .red : .gray).onTapGesture {
                self.on.toggle()
                print("test view4, local toggle")
            }.padding()
            Text("Global").foregroundColor(Global.shared.on ? .red : .gray).onTapGesture {
                Global.shared.on.toggle()
                print("test view4, global toggle")
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}

struct TestView5: View {
    @ObservedObject var local: Local
    init(on: Bool) {
        self._local = ObservedObject(initialValue: Local(on))
        print("test view5 init, glabel on = \(Global.shared.on), local on = \(self.local.on)")
    }
    var body: some View {
        print("test view5 body, glabel on = \(Global.shared.on), local on = \(local.on)"); return
        VStack {
            Text("TestView5").padding()
            Text("Local").foregroundColor(local.on ? .red : .gray).onTapGesture {
                self.local.on.toggle()
                print("test view5, local toggle")
            }.padding()
            Text("Global").foregroundColor(Global.shared.on ? .red : .gray).onTapGesture {
                Global.shared.on.toggle()
                print("test view5, global toggle")
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, TestView3 depend on global, but TestView4(or TestView5) not designed to depend on global. You can say TestView4(or TestView5)  don't know global at all. But when TestView4(or TestView5)  as a sheet of TestView3, it will be affected whatever you want.

Comment: change code as "TestView4(on: false)", TestView4.init() still invoke. log: `test view4, global toggle
test view3 body, glabel on = false
test view4 init, glabel on = false, local on = false`

Comment: Ok, nevermind, just find and read what @ViewBuilder is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I found the reason.

@ObservedObject is not the same as @State. Apple do some special works on @State. @State will be kept in a special space independent on the view.

@ObservedObject will be initialized every time of UI refreshing. it cannot restore value like @State.

So, using @State instead of @ObservedObject.

Comment: you are wrong! '@ObservedObject' is in reality reference to ObservedObject, as '@State' is reference to State. The true is that State and ObservedObject are different but that is the only true information you published. Please, remove your answer .... don't make the readers to be more confused as before.

Comment: Welcome to discussing. What is wrong? I can not find it in your comment. Please make your point clear. Maybe I was wrong, but your words do not help, for me or other readers.

Comment: ObservedObject as well as State are structs, both of them conform to DynamicProperty protocol (stored variable that updates an external property of a view.) The view gives values to these properties prior to recomputing the view’s body. What you wrote is total mess, sorry.

Comment: Yes, what u say is well known(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/observedobject). Not just read, please try. My point is they are not totally the same. ObservedObject has Side Effects, it is very dangerous. Please use it carefully or even not use it.

Comment: which part of doc are you talking about? which side effects are you talking about? please, i don't like to argue with nobody, but don't mix a s... using ObservedObject is common and suggested practice, dangerous is your "investigation" and interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: **You not able to avoid that**. Why? Every time the value of TestView3 property wrapped in State or ObservedObject changed, it recalculates its body. Even in case the TestView3 or TestView4 will be in-depended from this values, this part of declaration

```
if self.sheetShowingId == 4 {
    TestView4(on: self.global.on)
} else {
    TestView5(on: self.global.on)
}
```

represents one View and its body must be reevaluated.

Q2: This has no simple answer, just because we do not know too much about implementation details of each other. At least I suggest you not to be dependent on your investigation :-). So or so, it is easy to see that **you create new (local copy) of your model Local()** in TestView5.init.

```
init(on: Bool) {
    self._local = ObservedObject(initialValue: Local(on))
    print("test view5 init, glabel on = \(Global.shared.on), local on = \(self.local.on)")
}
```

Do you really like to have different (independent) model every time SwiftUI needs to refresh its Views? I don't think so ...

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am clear about Q1. For Q2, yes, I don't want create new copy. Here is a user case: I will choose tags for a book, the book already has tag A\B\C in BookView, then I show a tag selector sheet(TagSelectionView) for this book, I want tag A\B\C already selected in sheet, I can modify the selection(ObservedObject), eg as A\C\G. In the meantime, a global value changed, BookView body updated - TagSelectionView init() - TagSelectionView body updated. Thus the selection(ObservedObject) will be reset as A\B\C in TagSelectionView init(). HOW to avoid this? any solution?

Comment: all you need to do (and to understand) is to separate business logic and / or data from your UI (presentation). Yes I know, almost all SwiftUI tutorials show us the opposite, but remember, if you find such a "trouble" as in your case, it is time to rethink what are you doing and it is better to return back. Otherwise your code will be soon hard to maintain  and full of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provide a new solution for this in iOS14: @StateObject, it is just the same as @State for Class which comfort ObservableObject.